# I don't know why it results in `undefined` when I used tweet_mode='extended' in Twitter API get function() on Node.js

Tags: api, twitter, full-text-search

I have a few question.
I would like to get twitter full-text, so I used get() function but it truncate when it returned.
like this :

```
'RT @Journeyto100k_: Google was not the first search engine, but quickly became the standard. Internet explorer even came preloaded on every…',
'RT @ApolloCurrency: Check out our latest blog post! In case you missed it.                          \n\n"Apollonauts Unveil Wiki…',
```

I used tweet_mode ='extended' and retweeted_status to get property full_text
but it didn't work.

```
let keyword1 = T.get('search/tweets',  {
            q:  'Crypto Currency crypto currency since:2019-04-15', count: 100, request: tweet_mode='extended' },async function (err, data, response) {
            let addr;
            let text = data.statuses.map(retweeted_status=>retweeted_status.text);
            console.log(text);
```

I expect the output of get() result to be full-text, but the actual output is text truncated.
+ In further more,
`data` obejct has 'full-text' property, but it returns text truncated.
like this :

```
{ created_at: 'Fri Apr 19 04:22:40 +0000 2019',
       id: 1119093934167212000,
       id_str: '1119093934167212032',
       full_text:
        'RT @Drife_official: DRIFE presented at Trybe’s first annual Endless Dappathon\n @trybe_social \n#cryptocurrency #drife…',
       truncated: false,
       display_text_range: [Array],
       entities: [Object],
       metadata: [Object],
       source:
        '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>',
       in_reply_to_status_id: null,
       in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
       user: [Object],
       geo: null,
       coordinates: null,
       place: null,
       contributors: null,
       retweeted_status: [Object],
       is_quote_status: false,
       retweet_count: 330,
       favorite_count: 0,
       favorited: false,
       retweeted: false,
       possibly_sensitive: false,
       lang: 'en' },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
T.get('search/tweets', {
            q, count, tweet_mode: 'extended'},async function (err, data, response) {
            let text = data.statuses.map(status=>status.full_text);
```

I have missed `full_text` instead of `text`.

and ONLY `RT(retwitt)`is truncated. another didn't truncate.